# Flutter: How to get a value inside ThemeData?

Tags: flutter, themedata

I'm trying to style my app globally and I have some questions about hot the properly retrieve the value like this!

This code it's not working because there is no `context` at this point, but is there some way to get this value?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
  useMaterial3: true,
  
  // Text Style
  textTheme: TextTheme(
    titleMedium: GoogleFonts.nunito(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, letterSpacing: -1, fontSize: 16),
  ),

  // AppBar
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of globally declaring theme data, use a class with static method returning themeData with context as parameter:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeClass.getThemeData(context),
    home: const HomePage(),
  );
}

class ThemeClass {
  static ThemeData getThemeData(BuildContext context) {
    final lightTheme = ThemeData(
      useMaterial3: true,

      // Text Style
      textTheme: TextTheme(
        titleMedium: GoogleFonts.nunito(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, letterSpacing: -1, fontSize: 16),
      ),

      // AppBar
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
      ),
    );

    return lightTheme;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create dark & light mode extension

```
extension Context on BuildContext {
     bool get isDarkMode => Theme.of(this).brightness == Brightness.dark;
}
```

Create your them file

```
class ConstTheme {
  /// Light theme color
  static ThemeData light = ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    fontFamily: 'DM Sans',
    colorSchemeSeed: ConstColor.primary,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: ConstColor.white,
    textTheme: const TextTheme(
      titleSmall: TextStyle(color: ConstColor.black),
      titleMedium: TextStyle(color: ConstColor.black),
    ),
    cardTheme: CardTheme(
      margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
      elevation: 2.0,
      color: ConstColor.white,
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
    ),
  );

  /// Dark theme color
  static ThemeData dark = ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    fontFamily: 'DM Sans',
    colorSchemeSeed: ConstColor.primary,
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xff151616),
    cardTheme: CardTheme(
      margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
      elevation: 2.0,
      color: const Color(0xff1C1E1F),
      // surfaceTintColor: const Color(0xff1C1E1F),
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      // shadowColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
    ),
  );
```